# Adding a bulk of items in the middle of a sparse array

Tags: javascript, pagination, underscore.js

I'd like to add a bulk of items into a sparse array, starting at a certain index.
I came along this requirement in order to accomplish client side pagination while **not retrieving all data from server** (assuming server returns the **right** data, given the required indexes).

To keep right indexes when "Skipping" and "Taking", I need to store the items in a sparse array. Besides relevant indexes, other places in array might as well be `undefined`.

I wrote the following snippet of code, assuming `bulk` is the retrieved chunk of items from Server, and `index` is where the first item should be placed.

```
    items = new Array(totalItemsPossibleCount);
    items = items.slice(-index)
                 .concat(bulk)
                 .concat(items.slice(index+bulk.length));
```

1. Is there a shorter way to do so?
2. Can this be achieved with [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/) in more readable way?

Comment: Your problem starts with "I need to store the items in a sparse array". You really really don't need to store the items in a sparse array here. Sparse arrays are not just slow, they're also not really conceptually arrays. You can use an object as a map for example, or better yet have objects for pages and a non sparse array for those. Remember, you also have a bunch of other collections available at your disposal, a deque might be a good choice here too if users usually navigate to adjacent pages.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to worry about sparse arrays in JavaScript and there is no need to instantiate with the Array constructor. If you insert into a random index then the rest of the array is just padded with `undefined` references:

```
var items = [];
items[5] = 'foo';
console.log(items); // [5: "foo"]
items.toString();   // ",,,,,foo"
```

To add new items into the middle of an array you can use the [`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) function:

```
items.splice(index, 0, bulk);
```

The `index` is where to start adding items, `0` is how many items to remove after that point, and `bulk` is the new items to add at that point. Splice acts on the array directly, and returns any items that were removed.

Comment: That will work for a single item. I want to add a bulk which is **array of items**. I was using Array C'TOR to boost performance. I saw [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7032550/javascript-insert-an-array-inside-another-array) you can use `splice` in the manner I'd love to. The latter actually answers my question.

Comment: @user40171 Sorry, yes you can use `apply` with the arguments in order to add an array.

Answer (score 2):

As [Jlivings points out](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/46450/14370), `splice` is what you're looking for. To use it for multiple items you could conceivably use `apply`:

```
var args = [index, 0].concat(bulk);
items.splice.apply(items, args);
```

*Edit:* Ah, shucks. Didn't see your comment on jlivings' answer; you obviously already found the same code solution over on SO.

Comment: This doesn't work if index is greater than the array length. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34534295/can-array-splice-be-used-to-create-a-sparse-array-by-adding-an-element-at-an-i